# Is there a more efficient way to pull data out of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have block of code that calls function `products_api_get_lowest_priced_offers` that may return a single record or multiple records.  From that block of code I call `def parse price` which will parse a record and return the fields in a dict.  I did this to make things more efficient by storing the code that walks the data in one place. Instead, it gives me code that I need two very similar blocks of code that pulls the values out of the dictionary (depending if I get one or more records back).  Is there a more efficient way?

```
def parse_price(sku_multi_sku):
  parsed_results=dict();
  parsed_results['ASIN'] = sku_multi_sku['Product']['Identifiers']['MarketplaceASIN']['ASIN']['value']
  parsed_results['SellerSKU'] = sku_multi_sku['Product']['Identifiers']['SKUIdentifier']['SellerSKU']['value']
  return parsed_results

......
......
            lowest_offer = products_api.get_lowest_priced_offers_for_sku(marketplace_id, skus)
            lowest_offer_dict = lowest_offer.parsed

            if type(lowest_offer_dict) is list:
                for sku_multi_sku in lowest_offer_dict:
                    results=parse_price(sku_multi_sku)
                    ASIN=results['ASIN'].              #this block is repeated below
                    SKU=results['SellerSKU']           #this block is repeated below
                    single_insert = (ASIN, SellerSKU)  #this block is repeated below
                    full_insert.append(single_insert)  #this block is repeated below
                

            else:
                results = parse_price(sku_multi_sku)
                ASIN = results['ASIN']
                SKU = results['SellerSKU']
                single_insert = (ASIN, SellerSKU)
                full_insert.append(single_insert)
                                   
          
    cursor.executemany("INSERT into  tbl_update (ASIN, SellerSku) VALUES (%s, %s)", full_insert)
    db.commit()
```

Comment: it isn't good if one argument return different data types, maybe try to change `lowest_offer.parsed` such than it always return list event if is only one offer found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could eliminate the redundancy as follow:

```py
    # (...)
    lod = lowest_offer_dict
    if not isinstance(lod, list):
        lod = [lod]
    for sku_multi_sku in lod:
        results = parse_price(sku_multi_sku)
        # ...
```

Alternatively, you could make a companion function to `parse_price` that returns a list of tuples (the ones you currently place in `full_insert`):

```py
def parse_prices_to_tuples(lod):
    if not isinstance(lod, list):
        lod = [lod]
    tuples = [
        (r['ASIN'], r['SellerSKU'])
        for sku_multi_sku in lod
        for r in [parse_price(sku_multi_sku)]
    ]
    return tuples

# and in your code
full_insert = parse_prices_to_tuples(lowest_offer.parsed)
```